# Let $m(t)$ be an unknown function of $t$. What is the derivative of the integral $\int_0^t m(t-s) \,ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, renewal-processes

I am working on a problem which involves the renewal equation of a renewal process, and I need to find the derivative of the integral as above. One of my classmate told me it is $m(t) - m(0)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I don't understand how....

Comment: If you know convolutions, then you get another sort of solution, but it's essentially a change of variable.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: by symmetry, $\int_0^t m(t-s)\,ds = \int_0^t m(s)\,ds$.  Now it's easy to see how to use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You get $m(t)$, not $m(t)-m(0)$.

Comment: I get the second part, but I don't understand the part where $\int_0^t m(t-s) \,ds$ = $\int_0^t m(s) \,ds$. Sorry for asking stupid questions...

Comment: use the change of variable, $u=t-s$, you get $\int_0^tm(t-s)ds=\int_t^0 m(u) (-du)=\int_0^tm(u)du$. Now, it doesn't matter which variable you use in your integration. so the last  is the same as $\int_0^tm(u)du$.

Comment: @codelearner: Drawing a picture may help too.  It's the area under the same curve, reflected horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

That's almost correct. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have:

$$\int_0^t m(t-s)\ ds = \int_0^t m(s)\ ds =  M(t) - M(0)$$

The reason why $m(t-s)$ can be substituted by $m(s)$ here can be seen by a $u$-substitution, but because intuitively at $s=0$, the start of the interval, we have that $m(t-s) = m(t-0)=m(t)$. However, at the end of the interval, we have that $s = t$ so $m(t-s) = m(t-t) = m(0)$. This is the same as looking at $m(0)$ to $m(t)$, it's just that your original integral is almost going from "right-to-left" in a sense, while the $m(s)$ substitution is going "left-to-right" if you think about integrals as moving from start to end. [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u2nxrrvkji) may help you see how they're symmetric. You can see how one is just a flipped version of the other, yet the area between the curves and the x-axis is the same in both the regular version and the flipped/symmetric version, so the integrals are the same.

We call $M$ an "antiderivative" of $m$.

However then if we are looking for the derivative,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t m(t-s)\ ds = \frac{d}{dt}(M(t) - M(0)) = m(t)$$

We have $\frac{d}{dt}M(t) = m(t)$ because $M$ is an antiderivative of $m$. Furthermore we have that $\frac{d}{dt}M(0) = 0$ since it's a constant. Hence we have that it's $m(t)$.

Comment: why does $\int_0^t m(t-s) \,ds$ = $\int_0^t m(s) \,ds$ ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please let me know if that helps!